# Intellij IDEA. Several SBT consoles

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

How I can run several SBT consoles in Intellij IDEA 12? I need it because I want to run 3 project modules, but when I run first it blocks SBT console until I kill process. I can achieve same result using 3 command line windows (cmd) but I want to run all from IDE.
P.S. I have installed `sbt` plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You could open multiple terminal windows in the IDE and use SBT (see highlighted area):

[image]